# problems with static resources, can not access public folder nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

okay, I'm having trouble accessing pictures from a node server folder, previously all this was on a xammp stack, which i'm converting over to a react-app. I'm getting hung up on accessing static folders - as nothing I try seems to work.

the folder structure is:

```
project
    ->client
    ->server
        ->public
            ->pictures
                ->receiving
                    ->front
                    ->back
                    ->misc
```

index.js/server

```
const {http,app,server,io,express} = require('./socketServer.js');
const cors = require("cors");
const Path = require('path');
const router = require('./router');

app.use(cors());
app.use('/pictures', express.static(Path.join(__dirname,'/public/pictures')));
app.use(router);

server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

router/server

```
const express=require('express');
const router=express.Router();
const redirect =process.env.REDIRECT;

router.get('/', (req, res)=> {
    res.redirect(redirect); //localhost:3000
})
module.exports = router;
```

socketServer/server

```
const http = require('http');
const socketio = require('socket.io');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketio(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    credentials: true
  }
});


module.exports = {app,http,server,io,express};
```

client code

```
import {PICTURE_ENDPOINT} from '../../config'; //localhost:5001
const picHelp = ['front',"back","misc"]

const pics = pictures.map((x,i)=>
    {
    return(
        <div className="matPicDiv" key={`matpic:${i}${x}${picHelp[i]}`}>
            <a href={`${PICTURE_ENDPOINT}/pictures/receiving/${picHelp[i]}/${x}`} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
                <img className="matPic" src={`${PICTURE_ENDPOINT}/pictures/receiving/${picHelp[i]}/${x}`} alt="something went wrong" />
            </a>
        </div>
    )
}
```

before I was accessing the images from the xammp stack (slightly different code with a different end point)- now that I'm trying to access from the node folder it fails.

Comment: "it fails." -- how?

Comment: 1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Compare the URLs in the Network tab of your browser's Developer tools with the path on the disk.

Comment: they have been compared - they match. my assumption is the router redirect might be getting in the way?

Comment: which URL are you trying to fetch when you get the 404?

Comment: what's the content of `../../config`?

Comment: oh, that just maps .env.dev variables into react so that I don't have to use REACT_APP in front of env variables for them to be recognized.
the variable that's coming out of that is just the string 'localhost:5001'

Answer (score 0):

so this was the solution - I would love to understand why this worked.

```
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static(Path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/pictures', express.static(__dirname + "/public/pictures"));
app.use(router);
```

it would appear that you need to 'set up' the static folder before you describe how to access it?